# Is this type of code called a DSL?

Tags: ruby

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_object, except: [:index, :create]
end
```

Adding methods directly into a class or calling a function as such.

I've created a `DefaultControllerConcern` it has all the CRUD methods inside it.

```
module DefaultControllerConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def index
      render_index(filters(find_objects), {}, serializer)
    end

    def show
      render_show(find_object, serializer)
    end

    def create
      object = model_class.new(object_params)
      modify_create(object)
      object.save
      render_create(object, serializer)
    end

    def update
      object = find_object
      modify_update(object)
      object.update(object_params)
      render_update(object, serializer)
    end

    def destroy
      object = find_object
      side_effects_destroy(object)
      render_destroy(object.destroy, object)
    end
end
```

It has some private methods inside that has to be implemented in the class extending it.

How do I create this type of syntax.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_object, except: [:index, :create]
  default_controller_actions :create,:show,:destroy
  destroy_side_effect :send_email
  create_side_effect :add_default_user

  def add_default_user(object)
    object.user = current_user
  end

  def send_email(object)
    Email.send
  end
end
```

What should I read up on. Is this a DSL?

Edit1:

```
destroy_side_effect :send_email

def self.destroy_side_effect(method_names)
  self.define_method(:destroy_side_effect) do
   method_names.each do |method_name|
      self.send(method_name)
   end
  end
end
```

I need to go check if this executes correctly. And if it can be added from the concern.

Comment: I don't think there's really a yes-or-no answer to this. Yeah, I guess you could consider it a DSL to some extent.

Comment: How do you define "DSL"?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia's DSL Page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language):

"A domain-specific language is somewhere between a tiny programming language and a scripting language, and is often used in a way analogous to a programming library. The boundaries between these concepts are quite blurry, much like the boundary between scripting languages and general-purpose languages."

According to that, it *might* be considered a DSL. On the other hand, when I see that code (especially when imagining the method calls with parentheses), I just see regular code design. If we were to call this a DSL, then could we also call pretty much *any* programming interface (class, module, etc.) a DSL?

The problem is that (as far as I know) there is no clear explanation differentiating between DSL and any programming interface.

If you mean how would I create methods that would be called like `destroy_side_effect` in the code above, then that is simply a matter of defining class methods (this is what `attr_accessor` does). The simplest way to declare a class method to use `self`, like this:

`def self.destroy_side_effect
  # ...
end`

Comment: My last sentence was, is this a DSL? Thank you, you helped me on that one, but how do I create this type of syntax?

Comment: I've appended my answer to answer this question.

Comment: Something like this? Updating the question as I can't add code here.
I'll have to go sit and test it.

Comment: I probably don't completely understand your intent, but if it's possible, I think you would be better off implementing this code using normal constructs like class and instance methods without resorting to metaprogramming and DSL's -- and then, you could perhaps refine it if that would be helpful.